# video is not playing from node js stream

Tags: node.js, reactjs, video-streaming

I just started learning MERN and was building a video streaming platform.
For showing a sample video as stream , I wrote the following code on *node js (with express)*:

```
app.get("/video", (req, res) => {
  // const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "assest", "sample.mp4");
  const filePath = "assest/sample.mp4";
  const stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
  const size = stat.size;
  const range = req.headers.range;

  if (range) {
    const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
    const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : size - 1;
    const c = end - start;
    const chunkSize = c + 1;

    const header = {
      "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
      "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
      "Content-Length": chunkSize,
      "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
    };

    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { start, end });
    res.writeHead(204, header);
    fileStream.pipe(res);
  } else {
    const header = {
      "Content-Length": size,
      "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
    };
    res.writeHead(200, header);

    fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);
  }
});
```

[Here is the github repo for folder structure and additional code](https://github.com/dr-debugger/video-streaming/tree/a/server)

And on the client site to display it, I'm calling the api something like this:

```
<video
        controls
        autoPlay
        style={{ width: "400px" }}
        src="http://localhost:8080/video"
        type="video/mp4"
      ></video>
```

But the video is not playing.
If I sent the whole video as a static file , like this `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "assest", "sample.mp4"));` , it's working.
Can someone correct me here?

Comment: Since you implement you own range handling: Are you aware that [`res.sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) does the range handling for you?

Comment: I dont know that man, how does that work? explain pls

Comment: In response to a request with a `Range` header, `res.sendFile` looks at `res.req.headers.range` and sends only the requested range.